# Print name of parent for children that match a pattern in JSON and PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I would like to print the `name` of those packages that have a child whose `packageDescription` is 'ABC'.

As you can see from my output, I am seeing the package descriptions inside a data structure, but I do not know how I can access those values from my pipeline, so there is currently no filtering on package descriptions.
The desired output is a simple list of names.

The JSON, which is from a universal package feed and has been shortened a lot:

```
{
    "count":  62,
    "value":  [
                  {
                      "id":  "61979cf2-4ad4-4d6c-b8c7-b67787c4874d",
                      "name":  "pack-de",
                      "versions":  [
                                       {
                                           "id":  "760870c0-5fc5-4453-b7fa-4648cc99bfcb",
                                           "version":  "1.15.0-344001",
                                           "isLatest":  true,
                                           "packageDescription":  "ABC",
                                           "publishDate":  "2023-04-04T14:14:57.5035842Z"
                                       }
                                   ],
                      "_links":  {
                                     "self":  {
                                                  "href":  ""
                                              },
                                     "feed":  {
                                                  "href":  ""
                                              },
                                     "versions":  {
                                                      "href":  ""
                                                  }
                                 }
                  },
                  {
                      "id":  "fea11928-decb-4334-89b6-89915a3e07b9",
                      "name":  "pack-en",
                      "versions":  [
                                       {
                                           "id":  "02a839a1-0d4c-403f-a6c8-ac6e00dec723",
                                           "version":  "1.15.0-344001",
                                           "isLatest":  true,
                                           "packageDescription":  "ABC",
                                           "publishDate":  "2023-04-04T14:15:09.1276991Z"
                                       }
                                   ],
                      "_links":  {
                                     "self":  {
                                                  "href":  ""
                                              },
                                     "feed":  {
                                                  "href":  ""
                                              },
                                     "versions":  {
                                                      "href":  ""
                                                  }
                                 }
                  },
                  {
                      "id":  "a5bb64b7-37c5-4ef4-ae0e-5e95a2a85ae3",
                      "name":  "pack-zh-cn",
                      "versions":  [
                                       {
                                           "id":  "79dee41e-824f-41e5-aa4b-b7126adb8053",
                                           "version":  "1.13.2-343998",
                                           "isLatest":  true,
                                           "packageDescription":  "AZ",
                                           "publishDate":  "2023-04-04T14:11:00.2381001Z"
                                       }
                                   ],
                      "_links":  {
                                     "self":  {
                                                  "href":  ""
                                              },
                                     "feed":  {
                                                  "href":  ""
                                              },
                                     "versions":  {
                                                      "href":  ""
                                                  }
                                 }
                  }
              ]
}
```

My PowerShell

```
$PackageInfo = ConvertFrom-Json -inputObject $myJson
$description = "ABC"
$PackageInfo.value | select name, versions, @{Name = $description; Expression = { ($_.versions.packageDescription | Where-Object $_.packageDescription -eq $description) }}
```

The current output I get:

```
name       versions                                                                                                                                             ABC
----       --------                                                                                                                                             ---
pack-de    {@{id=760870c0-5fc5-4453-b7fa-4648cc99bfcb; version=1.15.0-344001; isLatest=True; packageDescription=ABC; publishDate=2023-04-04T14:14:57.5035842Z}}    
pack-en    {@{id=02a839a1-0d4c-403f-a6c8-ac6e00dec723; version=1.15.0-344001; isLatest=True; packageDescription=ABC; publishDate=2023-04-04T14:15:09.1276991Z}}    
pack-zh-cn {@{id=79dee41e-824f-41e5-aa4b-b7126adb8053; version=1.13.2-343998; isLatest=True; packageDescription=AZ; publishDate=2023-04-04T14:11:00.2381001Z}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're looking for *filtering* instead of *selecting*, for that you can use `Where-Object`:

```
$description = 'ABC'
(ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $myJson).value |
    Where-Object { $_.versions.packageDescription -eq $description } |
    ForEach-Object name
```

With the Json in question this would result in:

```
pack-de
pack-en
```

If you want to get *objects* out of it instead of *values*, you can use `Select-Object` but you need to filter beforehand:

```
$description = 'ABC'
(ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $myJson).value |
    Where-Object { $_.versions.packageDescription -eq $description } |
    Select-Object name, @{ N='packageDescription'; E={ $_.versions.packageDescription }}
```

Which results in:

```
name    packageDescription
----    ------------------
pack-de ABC
pack-en ABC
```

Comment: Thank you very much! In this first step I wanted values, but for the next step I need to get  objects, so this was a valuable answer.